# Hide Defined Product Category and Product Subcategory if User Not Logged In

Tags: categories, hook-woocommerce

We are configuring a WooCommerce website.
I'd like some help with a code for the theme functions.php.

I need to hide defined categories for users not logged in.
Actually, there are two categories, one on the store/home page and one is a subcategory on a category page.
The categories are listed in the left menu as well as boxed containers with images.
It must be also removed from displaying where it's in menus and widgets.

I was able to hide the products in those categories by the product tag.
But, the category still shows up.

I tried this but I still see the categories listed. That snippet just hides products in the defined categories.
I understand to use "if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {" but am not using it until I get it to work.

```
// Hide products in specific category from not logged-in users
// https://www.themelocation.com/woocommerce-hide-specific-products-from-log-out-customers/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'exclude_products_fom_unlogged_users', 10, 2 );
function exclude_products_fom_unlogged_users( $tax_query, $query ) {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array('category-slug1', 'category-slug2'),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
    }
    return $tax_query;
}
```

And, this didn't work, either. (I don't want the orderby ID, but by how I have them listed in the product category configuration page.).

```
$args = array(
'depth' => 1,
'hide_empty' => 1,
'orderby' => 'ID',
'exclude' => '855, 945',
'order' => 'ASC',
'title_li' => ''
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```